# Traversing a Golang Map

Tags: go

I initialized a variable named data like this:

```
   var data interface{}
```

Then I unmarshalled raw json into.

```
   err = json.Unmarshal(raw, &data)
```

I've run these two functions on it:

```
   fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(data))
   fmt.Println(data)
```

and those return this:

```
   map[string]interface {}
   map[tasks:[map[payload:map[key:36A6D454-FEEE-46EB-9D64-A85ABEABBCB7] code_name:image_resize]]]
```

and I need to access the "key". I have tried these approaches and a few more:

```
   data["tasks"][0]["payload"]["key"]
   data[0][0][0][0]
```

Those have all given me an error similar to this one:

```
    ./resize.go:44: invalid operation: data["tasks"] (index of type interface {})
```

Any advice on how to grab the "key" value out of this interface? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the json schema ahead of time?

Comment: @Logiraptor Yes, it's going to look like this {
  "tasks": [
    {
      "code_name": "image_resize",
      "payload": {
        "key": "36A6D454-FEEE-46EB-9D64-A85ABEABBCB7"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you already know your schema, the best way to do this is to unmarshal directly into structs you can use.

http://play.golang.org/p/aInZp8IZQA

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type msg struct {
    Tasks []task `json:"tasks"`
}

type task struct {
    CodeName string  `json:"code_name"`
    Payload  payload `json:"payload"`
}

type payload struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
}

func main() {
    var data msg
    raw := `{ "tasks": [ { "code_name": "image_resize", "payload": { "key": "36A6D454-FEEE-46EB-9D64-A85ABEABBCB7" } } ] }`

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(data.Tasks[0].Payload.Key)
}
```

---

If you insist on doing things the hard way using your original code, you need to do type assertions. I highly recommend avoiding this route when possible. It is not fun. Every step needs to be checked to ensure it matches the data structure you expect.

http://play.golang.org/p/fI5sqKV19J

```
if m, ok := data.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
    if a, ok := m["tasks"].([]interface{}); ok && len(a) > 0 {
        if e, ok := a[0].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            if p, ok := e["payload"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                if k, ok := p["key"].(string); ok {
                    fmt.Println("The key is:", k)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

In response to Goodwine's question: You can read further about how to marshal and unmarshal by reading the encoding/json godoc. I suggest starting here:

- http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal
- http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

Comment: I was doing it the hard way, and yours.... it is way more simpler, and good looking, where can I read a doc about that?

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Thanks again Stephan, it's been a joy picking up Golang

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Thank you, I was doing something kind of ugly here: http://play.golang.org/p/0RQ3Mw8lzN

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use 3rd-party package like https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs

With `gabs`, The example above by @stephen-weinberg can be written as:

```
raw := `{ "tasks": [ { "code_name": "image_resize", "payload": { "key": "36A6D454-FEEE-46EB-9D64-A85ABEABBCB7" } } ] }`
j, _ := gabs.ParseJSON([]byte(raw))

fmt.Println("The key is", j.S("tasks").Index(0).S("payload", "key").Data().(string))
```

other popular json handling packages I've stumbled upon are: https://github.com/bitly/go-simplejson and https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason.

Comment: Love these additional json packages! Thanks for sharing!